# WebTestClient used multiple times returns empty body sometimes

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-boot-test

not sure, why this could be an issue, but I can't stabilize my unit-tests.

Here some snippets from my testclass:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = { "spring.main.web-application-type=reactive" })
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
public class SolrControllerV1Test {
  @Inject
  ApplicationContext context;
  @LocalServerPort
  int port;

  private WebTestClient client;
  @TestConfiguration
  static class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    public TestingAuthenticationProvider testAuthentiationManager() {
      return new TestingAuthenticationProvider();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityConfig(ServerHttpSecurity http, ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
      AuthenticationWebFilter webFilter = new AuthenticationWebFilter(authenticationManager);
      return http.addFilterAt(webFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
          .authorizeExchange()
            .anyExchange()
            .authenticated()
          .and()
          .build();
    }
  }
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
      this.client = WebTestClient.bindToApplicationContext(context).configureClient().responseTimeout(Duration.ofDays(1L)).baseUrl("http://localhost:" + port).build();
    }

    private void defaultCheck(ResponseSpec spec) {
      spec.expectStatus().isOk().expectBody().jsonPath("$.response.numFound").hasJsonPath();
    }
  @Test
  @WithMockUser(roles = { "ADMIN" })
  public void simpleUsrSelect() throws Exception {
    ResponseSpec spec = this.client.get().uri("/" + serviceVersion + "/usr/select?q=*:*&fq=*:*&fl=USRTYP,USRKEY,USRCID&rows=1&start=10&sort=last_update desc").exchange();
    defaultCheck(spec);
  }

  @Test
  @WithMockUser(roles = { "ADMIN" })
  public void simpleCvdSelect() throws Exception {
    ResponseSpec spec = this.client.get().uri("/" + serviceVersion + "/cvd/select?q=*:*&rows=10000").exchange();
    defaultCheck(spec);
  }
.
.
.
}
```

There are some more unit-tests there, some of which are long running (>1sec).  If I have enough unit-tests in the class (~5-8), of which 1 or 2 are taking a bit longer, the unit-tests start to break.  This looks like a thread safety issue, but I don't know, what I'm doing wrong.  Any ideas?

**EDIT**
Here the Server Part that made trouble:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN','TENANT')")
public Mono<ServerResponse> select(ServerRequest request) {
  return request.principal().flatMap((principal) -> {
    return client.get().uri(f -> {
              URI u = f.path(request.pathVariable("collection")).path("/select/").queryParams(
                  queryModifier.modify(principal, request.pathVariable("collection"), request.queryParams())
                  .onErrorMap(NoSuchFieldException.class, t -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Collection not found"))
                  .block()).build();
              return u;
            })
        .exchange()
          .flatMap((ClientResponse mapper) -> {
            return ServerResponse.status(mapper.statusCode())
              .headers(c -> mapper.headers().asHttpHeaders().forEach((name, value) -> c.put(name, value)))
              .body(mapper.bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class), DataBuffer.class);
          })
          .doOnError(t -> handleAuthxErrors(t, principal, request.uri()));
  });
}
```

If I add a `publishOn(Schedulers.elastic)` right after the .exchange() part, it seems to be working.  Since this is trial&error, and I don't really understand why the publishOn fixes the problem, does anybody else know?  I'm not even sure, whether using springs reactive Webclient is blocking in this case, or not...

Thanks, Henning

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here at a first glance; if you can come up with a repro project you should submit that as an issue to the Spring Boot project. Can you also reduce the scope of that? Maybe remove security?

Comment: It might be, that it has something to do with the way I programmed the server, and not even a test-issue, since that now breaks partly reproducible, with response cut off always at the same part, but not in all cases, although I do the same request.